# File upload Android defining path

Tags: android, upload, path

I'm trying to upload a file to web server.But i'm having file not found exception.I think error comes from the path which i defined.my path is Sd card/Android/data/ic_launcher.png

Can anyone help me to give the path correctly.Please guys....

Comment: what im trying is this.is this correct.Please tel me.
String SDcard = ""+Environment.getExternalStorageState();

String fullpath=SDcard+"/Android/data/ic_launcher.png";

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() not Environment.getExternalStorageState() and this returns String no need to concatenate these with "".

Comment: thankx for the concern.I tried.same exception is coming...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/ic_launcher.png");
```

add this permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: thanks, but error continues. File not found exception./mnt/sdcard/Android/data/ic_launcher.png[no such file or folder]. Please help me out

Comment: Do you have such type of folder or file present in sdcard ?

Comment: Yes Chirag.Im having that kind of folder

Comment: Have you give read and write permission of sdcard in manifest file?

Comment: what should i give.write permission??

Comment: I added those permissions.Still same result''''

Comment: I think there is .nomedia file in your /Android/data folder . Please remove it and check again with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String SD_Card_Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

String Complete_Path =  SD_Card_Path  + "/Android/data/ic_launcher.png";
```

This is the tested code Add External Storage Read/Write Permission in your AndroidMenifest and your code will be run.

Comment: Can you please check this code.This is my source..
http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: pathToOurFile must be "/data/data/file_to_send.mp3" if file is saved in internal memory of device.